# How to access wifi on an android phone that comes without it?

Tags: wi-fi

I purchased a cheap smart watch [(this one)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00X9L8R7K). It doesn't support wifi. At the moment I can surf and watch videos by being connected via bluetooth to my tablet.

But I plan to root the device and install google play on it. I would like to install other apps on it afterwards too. It has a simcard slot and I can use a 2G network to do that.

But I am wondering if I could either buy a plug and play module or build something that would enable me to access wifi on the watch? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry you actually need a WiFi receiver to be able to access WiFi. If there's no hardware in it supporting WiFi, you cannot add that by means of software.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. But, you cannot use Wi-Fi by just installing some apps or modules.To be able to use Wi-Fi, your smartphone must have a wireless receiver. If your watch's hardware doesn't include a Wifi receiver, you won't be able to access Wifi.